# How do I change the background of a text box in a SharePoint modern site?

Tags: modern-experience, sitepages

How do I change the background of a text box in a SharePoint modern site?

Like this?

[image]

Comment: I assume you refer to the text webpart. You can't create what you want OOTB. The closest you could get is to add that as an image but it might not look so good.